# OpenLiberty license production feature

Tags: open-liberty

what are the list of feature I can use in production for OpenLiberty?

I'm aware about 2Gb of HEAP memory limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the features listed on the open liberty website can be used in production. The full list is available [here](https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/feature/).

There is no 2GB heap limit for Open Liberty. Open Liberty is distributed under the standard EPLv1 license which has no limitation like this.  You are likely thinking of the WebSphere Liberty unsupported offering which has a production use license limitation, but this is not open source and is not Open Liberty.

Comment: I don't understand from the list if OSGI application are supported in openliberty. I saw only osgiconsole,
Feature like

        <feature>blueprint-1.0</feature>
        <feature>osgiAppConsole-1.0</feature>
        <feature>osgiAppIntegration-1.0</feature>

seems not availble am I wrong?

Comment: OSGi applications is not in Open Liberty. The osgi console feature is there mostly as a debug aid.

Answer (score 3):

OpenLiberty is an open source project with no strings attached, you can use whatever heap size you want. For Websphere Liberty on the other hand, it has a 2GB heap limit for developer/beta use

As for the feature list, you can find them here:
https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/feature/